# Adding a class to shortcode API

Tags: shortcode

So, I have the following shortcode which is included in two different pages.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'); ?>
```

Since two pages are using one identical shortocode, I am thinking of adding a class to the first page so that I can customize the first page shortcode only.

So here is my question.

1. Do you think that adding a class to the shortcode in the first page would allow me to customize it?
2. If so, what is the proper way of adding a class to the above code?
3. If not, what would be an option to add customization to a shortcode for only specific page?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it really is just for one page you could use a conditional on `the_ID();` from within your shortcode class (it is a custom shortcode right?)

```
$class = the_ID() == 213 ? "some-other-class" : "";
$myhtml = sprintf("<div class='some-class %1$s'>%2$s</div>",
   $class,
   $content);
```

The other option is to add parameters or "attributes" to your shortcode as in the codex. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Hope that helps.

Comment: `the_ID()` echoes the ID. You need `get_the_ID()`.

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress already has these classes in place for you, so you can basically target a specific page in CSS without adding additional classes. Take a look at the default [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) section in the codex, and more particulary at the [pages section](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Page)